# Can WebProvisioningProvider assembly version be automated in webtemp xml file?

Tags: visual-studio, site-definition, provisioning-providers

I have a basic site site definition I am attempting to provision with a custom `SPWebProvisioningProvider`.  I have the following attributes set in the webtemp xml file

> ProvisionAssembly="{assembly name}, Version={version number}, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={public key token}"

This is using the VS2010 site template project, with the custom provisioning provider defined in the same assembly as the site definition xml files.  I can move it to another assembly (and did for a while), but it doesn't seem warranted in this case.

Everything works fine when I put actual values for what I have in `{}`, but with the version number of the assembly auto revisioning the version number is different each build.

Is there a way to pull the version number from the assembly and auto-populate it in the webtemp xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Visual Studio 2010 Replaceable Parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231545.aspx